# Difference power sum estimation

Tags: inequality, summation, estimation

I'm looking for estimates of this type of sum

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left|i^{-1}-j^{-1}\right|^{4k}$$

where $k\in(0,1)$.

Interesting upper/lower inequalities for

$$|i-j|^{4k}$$

could work too, but estimates of the sum would be preferable.

So far I have the classic result

$$\min\left(1,2^{4k-1}\right)\left(|i|^{4k}+|j|^{4k}\right)\leq|i-j|^{4k}\leq\max\left(1,2^{4k-1}\right)\left(|i|^{4k}+|j|^{4k}\right).$$

Comment: Restrict to i < j so you can get rid of the absolute values.

Comment: What would it change in the inequality? I would still need a difference and thus absolute values. Or are you suggesting other approach?